# Custom LogFormat - Log all headers

Tags: apache, apache2

Some mobile gateways are passing custom headers to my site. These headers are passed in various formats, sometimes, x-msisdn, sometimes x-up-calling-line-id and others. How can I log all headers passed in my custom log format?

Comment: You can't do this with only Apache and mod_log_config. You can with mod_security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via Apache HTTPD I'm not sure how to log **all** headers - only how to log one header that you know about.

Using the standard Apache httpd module mod_log_config you can specify the following option in the CustomLog directive.

%{Foobar}i  The contents of Foobar: header line(s) in the request sent to the server. Changes made by other modules (e.g. mod_headers) affect this.

**However** you could do this in jsp (if this is what you're using by chance)

```
<!-- method used to send request
<%= request.getMethod() %>

URI of the request
<%= request.getRequestURI() %>

  <%
     /*This method returns an enumeration of all the header names this 
       request contains.*/       
  java.util.Enumeration names = request.getHeaderNames();
  while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
     String hname = (String)names.nextElement();
  %>

     <%= hname %>
     <%= request.getHeader(hname) %>
  <%
  }
  %>
--!>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also sniff the network interface to do this.

Wireshark has tshark (apt-get install tshark)
tshark 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' -R'http.request.method == "GET" || http.request.method == "HEAD"'

(above came from http://andy.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/sniffing-http/ tshark is the new name for tethereal)

or use something like https://github.com/caesar0301/http-sniffer